# android Table layout wiht table read rows

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-tablelayout

I have table row inside table layout, I need to read all row and move data to sql. How i read table by row next row need to read row one and go to row 2 and read

code for insert into table row :

```
TableLayout l1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);
l1.setStretchAllColumns(true);
l1.bringToFront();

TableRow tr0 = new TableRow(getBaseContext());

TextView tv1 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
TextView tv2 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
TextView tv3 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
TextView tv4 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
TextView tv5 = new TextView(getBaseContext());

tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv5.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

tv1.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
tv2.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
tv3.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
tv4.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
tv5.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

tv1.setText(Integer.toString(id_row=id_row+1));
tv2.setText(e_entrbond_calcname.getText().toString());
tv3.setText(e_entrybonds_mdin1.getText().toString());
tv4.setText(e_entrybonds_dain1.getText().toString());
tv5.setText(e_entrybonds_details2.getText().toString());


tr0.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

tr0.addView(tv1);
tr0.addView(tv2);
tr0.addView(tv3);
tr0.addView(tv4);
tr0.addView(tv5);

l1.addView(tr0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for Reading values from TableRow;

```
TableLayout l1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);

for (int i = 0; i < l1.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = l1.getChildAt(i);

    if (child instanceof TableRow) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) child;

        for (int x = 0; x < row.getChildCount(); x++) {
            //View view = row.getChildAt(x);
            TextView text = (TextView)row.getChildAt(x); // get child index on particular row
            String title = text.getText().toString();
            Log.i("Value", title);      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thnxs sir :)
you saved me